# Do these graphs show that the regression assumptions are met?

Tags: multiple-regression, data-visualization, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

Is there any concern regarding this plot, specifically that it meets the homoscedasticity assumption? May I continue with multiple linear regression? How can I fix this?

My research is on household saving behavior.  The independent variables are: income, gender, financial literacy, age, deposit interest rate, education, and family size.
The dependent variable is savings amount. All values for the dependent variable are $\ge 0$.  The sample size without outliers is 181.

[image: histogram of residuals & scatterplot of residuals vs predicted]

Comment: The residual versus predicted plot showing lines with negative slope indicates this is some discete data. For this to be answerable, you need to give some context!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen All residual versus predicted plots imply a pattern of lines with negative slope; it's just a case of how obvious they are, as some may only be populated with one data point.

Comment: @Nick Cox: There is a cleat lower boundary on the left side ...

Comment: Indeed; I do agree. The inference that the response is bounded is clear. The OP told us that and it is clear any way. The inference that it is discrete is less secure. Savings are measured in some currency, which in principle we think is approximately continuous except that reported values are often rounded.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to assess the normality assumption is to make a qq-plot of the residuals, not a histogram.  That said, the distribution is probably good enough, especially considering the sample size.  Nor do I see a problem with heteroscedasticity.  You could always use a sandwich estimator for extra safety, but I'm not sure it's really necessary.

The biggest issue is that you have an obvious floor effect.  That is, savings cannot go below $0$. (Or can they? Do you know if any of these households are running up debt?  Does economic theory speak to that issue?)  Using a linear model is easy, and seemingly interpretable, but it actually prevents you from being able to think correctly about your data.  Arguably, you should be using a zero-inflated or hurdle model (presumably Gamma).  At a minimum, I would use curvilinear terms (e.g., splines) and make sure the model's behavior at the low end is sensible.

Comment: Question says that all responses are zero or positive. I agree with everything you say but would add a generalized linear model with log link as a possible model, likely over-simplified in part, but that is what models are for.

Comment: The "obvious floor effect" translates to pretty severe heteroscedasticity and substantial non-Normality (and non-symmetry) of residuals within a portion of the scatterplot. If there is any decent linear fit to be had, we can therefore be sure that its slope estimate will be *biased.*  One could view these data as if they were *censored* at zero, providing yet another modeling option. Using splines might give a better fit but will not resolve the problems with heteroscedasticity.